# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function. Unable to Correct it

Tags: javascript

I am unable to run the following code.
It shows me this error:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

```js
const Prom = async() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = 2;
    if (a == 2) {
      resolve('Its working');
    } else {
      reject('Its not working');
    }
  });
};
const final = await Prom();
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Prom = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = 2;
    if (a == 2) {
      resolve('Its working');
    } else {
      reject('Its not working');
    }
  });
};


const final = async () => {
  const result = await Prom();
  console.log(result);
};

final();
```

`await` can only be used inside an async function.

The error here is referring to the final variable. It has to be inside of an async function. Try using the below code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
const Prom = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = 2
    if (a == 2) {
      resolve('Its working')
    } else {
      reject('Its not working')
    }
  })
}

;(async function() {
  const final = await Prom()
  console.log(final)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = 2;
    if (a == 2) {
      resolve('Its working');
    } else {
      reject('Its not working');
    }
});
(async function() {
  const final = await prom;
  console.log(final)
})()
```

Comment: adding a verbal explanation can be helpful